# how to get 201 status code in web services in node js

Tags: json, node.js

How can i return the result of post method in api and also 201 status code? In this code the status code is 200 how can i change it to 201?

```
var request = require('request');

request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'URLPATH',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic Key'
  },
  body: {
"id":"1","message":"I am Good Developer."
}
}, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('Status:', response.statusCode); //get 201 status but received 200
  console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(response.headers));
  console.log('Response:', body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are calling a web service, is the web service that respond with 200 and not 201.

You need to change the web service code, no the client code.